# Google Sheets: Copy Rows Based on Condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I have got a sheet that contains a number of columns. I have tried creating a function in Google Apps Script to copy all the rows to another sheet which is working fine.

I would like to add a condition to which rows are copied, i.e. if column 'V' equals 'YES' then the row gets copied.

This is what I have so far. I have just started playing around with Google Apps Script and I don't have any other programming language experience. What I have gotten here is what I have found on this site and I have tried making changes based on trial and error so please bear with me :)

```
function prepareExport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Get year & month
  var now= new Date();
  var year = now.getYear();
  var thismonth = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var lastmonth = ("0" + now.getMonth()).slice(-2);

  // Source
  var lastmonthsheet = ss.getSheetByName([year] + "-" + [lastmonth]);
  var thismonthsheet = ss.getSheetByName([year] + "-" + [thismonth]);

  // Target
  var exportsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Export");

  // Set source ranges
  var lastmonthdata =                    lastmonthsheet.getSheetValues(2,1,lastmonthsheet.getLastRow(),21);
  var thismonthdata = thismonthsheet.getSheetValues(2,1,thismonthsheet.getLastRow(),21);

  // Write values
  exportsheet.getRange(exportsheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, lastmonthdata.length,21).setValues(lastmonthdata);
  exportsheet.getRange(exportsheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, thismonthdata.length,21).setValues(thismonthdata);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the value of cell Vx is "YES", get the values of row x**

1. Get the values for `cpy`, the rows whose column V is "YES"

   ```
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetname");

     var cpy = []; //arrays to be copied

     for (i=1;i<sheet.getLastRow();i++){
       var vRng = sheet.getRange(i,22);
       if (vRng.getValue() !== "YES"){continue} //"YES" is case sensitive
       cpy.push(vRng.getRow())
     }
     Logger.log(cpy);
   }
   ```
2. Use `cpy` in a for loop. `tcpy` gets the rest of the row (with values).

   ```
     for (i=0;i<cpy.length;i++){
       var tcpy = sheet.getRange(cpy[i],1,1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues());
     //in this for loop, you can add your setValues(tcpy)
     }
   ```